# How can i show form values in a modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-portal

I'm trying to do a modal that shows the values previously submitted in a form. I´m using ReactJs.

This is my ContactForm.js: where i define the different inputs, validations and functions.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import SubmitBtn from '../atoms/SubmitBtn';
import './ContactForm.css'
import './Modal.css'
import FormInput from '../molecules/FormInput'
import Modal from './Modal';


const ContactForm = () => {
  const [ isOpen, setIsOpen ] = useState(false)
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    key: '',
    value: ''
  })
  const [values, setValues ] = useState({
    name: '',
    lastname: '',
    email: '',
    confirmEmail: '',
    message: ''
  });

  const inputs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Name',
      required: true,
      pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]+$',
      errorMessage: 'Only letters are allowed '
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'lastname',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Last Name',
      required: true,
      pattern: '^[a-zA-Z]+$',
      errorMessage: 'Only letters are allowed '
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'email',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Email',
      required: true,
      errorMessage: 'Invalid email'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'confirmEmail',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Confirm Email',
      required: true,
      pattern: values.email,
      errorMessage: 'Emails don´t match'

    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'message',
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: 'Message',
      required: true,
      errorMessage: 'This field cannot be empty'
    }
  ]



    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
    e.preventDefault();
    for( let [key, value] of formData.entries()){
      setData({
        key: key,
        value:value
      })
    }
    setIsOpen(true)
    
  }

  const handleClose = () =>{
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValues({...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}); 
  }  

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal 
      open={isOpen} 
      handleClose={handleClose}
      data={data}      
      />
      
      <form className='contactForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {inputs.map((input) => (
          <FormInput 
          key={input.id} 
          {...input} 
          value={values[input.name]} 
          onChange={onChange}
          />
        ))}
        <SubmitBtn handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />    
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactForm
```

FormInput.js: in here i show the different input fields and the errorMessage for each corresponding input field.

```
import React from 'react'
import './FormInput.css';
import { Input } from '../atoms/Input';
import ErrorSpan from '../atoms/ErrorSpan';

const FormInput = (props) => {

  const { id, onChange, errorMessage, ...inputProps } = props;

  return (
    <div className='formInput'>        
         <Input 
         {...inputProps} 
         onChange={onChange} 
         /> 

        <ErrorSpan 
        errorMessage={props.errorMessage}
        />        
    </div>
  )
}

export default FormInput
```

Modal.js: Up to now i only have a button that triggers a function that updates the value of isOpen to false again for the modal to be closed. And if the open variable is true, the component renders the modal. The thing is how can i bring my data submitted in my form and display it in this modal?

```
import React from 'react'

const Modal = ({ open, handleClose, data }) => {
  if(!open) return null

  return (
    <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className="modal-container">
            <div className="modal">
                <input>{data.key}</input>
                <button onClick={handleClose} >Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set the state properly, it will return the last element in the code provided . so change it like this

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([])
......

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData(e.currentTarget)
    e.preventDefault();
let results = [];

    for( let [key, value] of formData.entries()){

   results.push({
        key: key,
        value:value
      })
    }  
    setData(results);
    
    setIsOpen(true)
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I would suggest to  use the modal in the contactForm.js then use the states,
or if you are not doing that way then use this method to get the actual form data and pass the data to the Component of modal

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    event.preventDefault();
    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(key, value);
    }
  };
```

the result can be used. I Hope this might give you idea  cheers ✨

Comment: I can see what you are doing in that function, but the issue is how can i pass the key and value to my modal component so that i can render those variables in the child component that would be `<Modal/>`

Comment: you can maintain the state then store the form data in state and pass it to the modal as props , actual problem is your setting state in a loop, see me new answer